# Given a Class object, how do i create an instance of a list of the class type that it references to

Tags: java, generics

This one is going to be tough to explain but I am going to try and keep it as simple as possible.
Lets say i have an Object called Car and i have a function that receives the following :

```
public void foo(Class<Car> type){
    // I want to create a list of this type, do something like this
    List<type> list = new List<type>
    // I know its not the way to do it but is there any way to do something like this
```

Long story short i want to create a list that will be a list of cars 
Is it possible given the Class object?

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to do this?  What are you trying to actually accomplish?

Comment: It's just an example, i dont want to start explaining about everything that is going on in my project because it will be long.

Comment: So `Class<Car>` represent the `Car` class. If you want a List of Car, you already have the known type: `List<Car>`, if you want a list of classes of car (???) you can do `List<Class<Car>>`, if don't know that it's a `Car` and want a generic type, look into generic methods.

You need to provide more context as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, the point is i dont know its a car, sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: You're going to need to distill what's going on in your project.  Writing code like this is often frowned upon because of it's unmaintainability.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention that you don't know the actual type (`Car`, in the example), I assume you're looking to use generics.

```
  public <T> void foo(Class<T> t) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
  }
```

So this is a generic method, so you can use the same type argument from the `Class` object to create your List. Though, I'm not sure why you'd want this. If you already have the type argument used for the `Class` object, then you don't really need the `Class` object for create your list. You could just do `List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>()`